# Variable calculated and returned in user-defined method not found?

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors

This is my code right now:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.PrintWriter; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.io.IOException;

public class IceCreamData 
{
    // method to calculation volume
    public static void printCylinderVolume(double cylinderRadius, double cylinderHeight){ 
        double cylinderVolume = Math.PI * Math.pow(cylinderRadius, 2) * cylinderHeight; 
        return cylinderVolume;
    }


    // method to calculate number of ice cream scoops
    public static double printNumScoops(double cylinderVolume){ 
        double numScoops = (cylinderVolume * 0.004329) * 30; 
        System.out.println("The number of scoops is " + cylinderVolume);
    }

// the main method
public static double main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    {

 //input the file and scanner and output file 
    File input = new File("project4Data.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(input); 
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("scoopResults.txt");

//declaring variables outside of while-loop in order to run 
    String iceName; // name of the ice cream
    double cylinderRadius; // cylider radius
    double cylinderHeight; // cylinder height
    int expirationYear; // expiration year

// while-loop to determine number of scoops in a container of ice cream
        while(in.hasNext())
        { 
            iceName = in.next(); // ice cream name 
            cylinderRadius = in.nextDouble(); // radius of the cylinder
            cylinderHeight = in.nextDouble(); // height of the cylinder
            //while-loop 
            while(cylinderRadius > 0 && cylinderHeight > 0 && expirationYear <= 2018){
                System.out.println(iceName); 
                printCylinderVolume(cylinderRadius, cylinderHeight);
                printNumScoops(cylinderVolume);
            }




        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to return the cylinder volume from the printCylinderVolume method to the main method, so that I can use it in the printNumScoops method. Right now I am getting an error saying that cylinderVolume is an unexpected return value, and another error saying that the printNumScoops method can't find cylinderVolume. Is cylinderVolume initialized/declared in the right places and does it need to be returned/stored in the main method differently to work?

Comment: `public static void`  then  `return cylinderVolume;` - nah that won't work

Answer (score 1):

Your method should return a `double`, not a `void`:

```
public static double printCylinderVolume(double cylinderRadius, double cylinderHeight) {
    // Here --^ 
    double cylinderVolume = Math.PI * Math.pow(cylinderRadius, 2) * cylinderHeight; 
    return cylinderVolume;
}
```

You may want to consider renaming the method, though, since it doesn't actually print anything, it just returns the calculation. `calcCylinerVolume` could be a more appropriate name.

Comment: I did that and it's still getting the error where it can't find the cylinderVolume variable in the printNumScoops method

Comment: Well you want to *store* the value that is returned `double cylinderVolume = printCylinderVolume(cylinderRadius, cylinderHeight);` - this is very basic java stuff, so I would encourage you to return to your textbooks

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect way in creating a method. For example, in this following method:

```
public static void printCylinderVolume(double cylinderRadius, double cylinderHeight){ 
    //         ^
   // the method need void return 


   double cylinderVolume = Math.PI * Math.pow(cylinderRadius, 2) * cylinderHeight; 


   return cylinderVolume;
   // But, you're returning double
}
```

You're creating a method with void return. but at the end of the method you are returning a double.

And in the following code:

```
// the main method
public static double main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

   ...
}
```

If you're trying to create a main method, then the above code is incorrect. main method should return a void like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ...
}
```

Please read more about Defining a method in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html